# Connect to wifi before Lubuntu install (prepare in live mode?)

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, usb, lubuntu

I am in the situation where only bootable external media I can use is an USB flash and only option I can use to connect to Internet is Wi-Fi.

I am trying to install Lubuntu on an older Acer laptop and I am having the issue with the grub installation, I've read that it can be solved by connecting the device to the Internet (people are also advising to select .../sdX instead of .../sda, but the installation is stuck there, so I am trying this way).

Also I would like for it to get any updates while installing, that's reason No.2.

So how would I connect to wifi, before the installation?
Can it somehow be prepared from the live run?

Lubuntu ISO I am using: lubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso

I will be grateful for any advice/help ! Thanks :)

(I am a linux sometimes-user, I know a few basic commands, but I am not an expert...)

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to what the GRUB problem is? Maybe that can be easily solved without going through all of this hassle.

Comment: @SimonQuigley it can be easily solved by internet access , I don't remember the problem specific message, but it is probably related to usb booting and the sdX targets as I've mentioned, however, this question is not directly related to this issue, this question really is just about if it is possible to connect to wifi before the instalation (and install updates).

Comment: Since grub install is at the end that must mean you created a partition already for the lubuntu install.

Comment: Yes, the formatting does happen before. But I guess it's somehow wrongly targeting USB instead of the install partition ?